# Export CSV of an smart group's contacts via REST API?

Tags: contacts, api, groups, rest

How can I make a REST API call to Civi that creates a CSV file with all the Contacts details (name, email, telephone...) from an specified Smart Group?

Thanks.

Comment: The REST api isn't capable of making a CSV, it can easily get you the members from the group but formatting those into a CSV is coding you would have to undertake in your code/system and is beyond the scope of CiviCRM. I'll post an answer with an example API call. EDIT The "review" screen helpfully doesn't show the comment which basically says what I said :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a csv directly from an API call. But it would be a very simple task to make an API call and then format the results as a csv. One simple option might be to use Google Apps Script to call the API then put the results into a spreadsheet, if you don't want to run this as a standalone script. Or any scripting language you might want to use will have plenty of Google results for creating a csv from an array, which is what the API will return.

Comment: That's great idea, thanks!